What are my duties as a Brahmachari dwija?
I am a Brahmachari of Yajur Veda Apastamba Sutra. I had my upanayanam years ago but I want to get back to my rituals. Apart from Sandhyavanadam, what are my daily duties and rituals? I am in college and unable to do homam etc.
Thanks
